# How to remote debug a Typescript node.js program

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

With this setup I'm able to remote debug js files (on my Raspberry Pi).
But I would like to break inside ts files just as I'm able to do while local debugging. Is this possible?

I tried with different param in launch.json but with no luck. sourceMaps and outFiles seem to have no effect.

launch.json

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach to Remote",
        "address": "192.168.0.222",
        "port": 9229,
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "remoteRoot": "/home/pi/BADGER/src",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/bin/**/*.js"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": true
}
```

Comment: I'm just verifying: 
Your IP is 192.168.0.222 and the port you're using for your node app is 9229.
In other words - go to the node folder, run `node index.js` or whatever you use and enter `http://192.168.0.222:9229`
Verify you see it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this article: [Debugging TypeScript in VS Code without compiling, using ts-node](https://medium.com/@dupski/debug-typescript-in-vs-code-without-compiling-using-ts-node-9d1f4f9a94a)

Again - given your node app runs on http://192.168.0.222:9229 (try to enter this path manually to verify)

Add this to `launch.json`

```
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9229,
        "address": "192.168.0.222",
        "restart": true,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": "/home/pi/BADGER/src"
    }
```

Comment: But how does this help me running it remotely (on a Raspberry Pi)?

Comment: Sadly the article did not provide info for my problem.